Matrix of the derivative of a differentiable function $f$ at the origin with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$.
Let $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y)):\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ be a differentiable function.Let $A$ denote the matrix of derivative of $f$ at the origin with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$.Assume $f(y,-x)=(v(x,y),-u(x,y))$ for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$.Which of the following statements are possibly true?

$(1)$.$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$(2)$.$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$(3)$.$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\
-1&-2
\end{bmatrix}$$(4)$.$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\
-1&2
\end{bmatrix}$


Let $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ then $f(y,-x)=(y,-x)$ therefore $f$ satisfies all the conditions.Here $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=y$.Therefore matrix of derivative of $f$ at the origin with respect to the standard basis of$\Bbb R^2$ is given by $A=\begin{bmatrix}u_x&u_y\\
v_x&v_y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}$.Therefore option (1) is correct.I am unable to solve this question completely and also unable to use the given information $f(y,-x)=(v(x,y),-u(x,y))$ for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$.Is there any general method to solve this problem?

Let $b=-x, a=y$ and rewrite $f(y,-x)$ in terms of $a,b$. Then compute the matrix of the derivative of $f$. If $x=y=a=b = 0$ then the two matrices will be equal and will exhibit some constraints. Then evaluate (1)-(4) above in this light.

I get $f(y,-x)=f(a,b)=(v(-b,a),-u(-b,a))$.So $A=\begin{bmatrix}v_a&-v_b\-u_a&u_b\end{bmatrix}$

@copper.hat Is it correct?

No. Note that $[{\partial f(a,b) \over \partial a}]_1 = v_y(-b, a)$. Stick with $v_x$ to represent ${\partial v(x,y) \over \partial x}$, etc, to avoid getting lost in symbols.

Sir i am confused with symbols.Can you please provide full solution.Thank you.

@copper.hat Sir,I am still waiting for your reply.

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
  B & = & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1\\
    - 1 & 0
  \end{array}\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Then for $v = (x, y)$, we are given
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f (B v) & = & B f (v) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, by differentiation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  D f (B v) B & = & B D f (v),\\
  D f (0) B & = & B D f (0),\\
  A B & = & B A,\\
  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    - A_{1 2} & A_{11}\\
    - A_{2 2} & A_{2 1}
  \end{array}\right) & = & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    A_{2 1} & A_{2 2}\\
    - A_{1 1} & - A_{1 2}
  \end{array}\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
This is necessary and sufficient, since if above holds you can take $f (v) = A
v$. Solving for $A$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
  A & = & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    a & - b\\
    b & a
  \end{array}\right), \quad a, b \in \mathbb{R} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence (1), (2), (4) work.

This is just a more direct version of the approach used in Kakashi's answer. That answer is elegant, but that elegance sidesteps some direct manual calculations that a learner might want to see.

We have differentiable function
$$f(x,y) := \begin{pmatrix} u(x,y) \\ v(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$$
and exactly one (additional) restriction on $f$
$$ \begin{pmatrix} u(y,-x) \\ v(y,-x) \end{pmatrix} = f(y,-x) = \begin{pmatrix} v(x,y) \\ -u(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$$
where the left equality is just the expansion of the middle expression by the definition. Take the derivative of both sides at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ to get the restriction on the derivative:
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
-\partial_2 u(y,-x) & \partial_1 u(y,-x) \\ 
-\partial_2 v(y, -x) & \partial_1 v(y,-x) 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\partial_1 v(x,y) & \partial_2 v(x,y) \\ 
-\partial_1 u(x,y) & -\partial_2 u(x,y) 
\end{pmatrix}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
-\partial_2 u(0,0) & \partial_1 u(0,0) \\ 
-\partial_2 v(0,0) & \partial_1 v(0,0) 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\partial_1 v(0,0) & \partial_2 v(0,0) \\ 
-\partial_1 u(0,0) & -\partial_2 u(0,0) 
\end{pmatrix} $$
Comparing entry-wise shows that $a := \partial_1 u(0,0) = \partial_2 v(0,0)$ and $b := \partial_2 u(0,0) = -\partial_1 v(0,0)$, and so the derivative of $f$ at the origin has the form
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 
a & -b \\ 
b & a
\end{pmatrix} $$
Of the options available, all but (3) have this form.

@ Nice explanation .Thank you sir.

Producing an $f$ that works will establish that an option is possible. For instance,  you can try:
$(1)  f(x,y)=(x,y)\\(2)  f(x,y)=(-y,x)\\(3)  f(x,y)=(x+2y,-x-2y)\\(4)f(x,y)=(2x+y,-x+2y).$
So just check if $f(y,-x)=(v(x,y),-u(x,y))$ for each.
We need $u(y,-x)=v(x,y)$ and $v(y,-x)=-u(x,y).$

For instance, in $(2),$ we have $u(x,y)=-y$ and $v(x,y)=x.$  So, $u(y,-x)=-(-x)=x=v(x,y).$
And $v(y,-x)=y=-(-y)=-u(x,y).$
So option $(2)$ is possible.

Although your solution is great,but is there any direct method to approach this problem?Can we extract any useful information from the question?

If there were more variables involved we probably couldn't do it.   I see it as a cute little problem.   Thanks btw.

It's a good Jacobian practice problem.

Your claim that there is only one $f$ with each Jacobian is incorrect. E.g. when $f(x,y)=(x+x^2,y)$, the Jacobian of $f$ at the origin is also the identity matrix.

Have I missed some assumption about what $f$, $u$, or $v$ can be? It seems to me that the idea that a function can be completely determined by its derivative at a single point is obviously untrue. Maybe you're interpreting $A$ as the global derivative matrix? Though that's explicitly not the case in the problem statement.

@AlexJones then that was a mistake,  and I only can establish that,  for instance,  $2)$ is possible, not whether one is not possible

@AlexJones Do you have any solution for this problem?

@SandeepTiwari See the solution written by Kakashi.

@AlexJones You don't have anything different?
